# option clash for amsmath

Tags: beamer, amsmath

How to resolve the issue of package `amsmath` being clash for `beamer`? I had used `tbtags` option to give equation number to the last splitted equation. I had used following packages in the preamble. Thanks in advance.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{xyz}{RGB}{0,102,102}

\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `beamer` document class loads the `amsmath` package automatically. Thus, you need to change

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
```

to

```
\documentclass[tbtags,11pt]{beamer}
```

That way, the `tbtags` option will be passed to the `amsmath` package right when it's loaded the first time.

Comment: Thank you. It works for me.